# Existing eclipse project to svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I have a eclipse project and I want to enable subversion for it. So I have setup subversion on my ubuntu server.

I can browse my repository with `http://svn.mydomain.net/myproject`.

In eclipse I do right-click on my project -> `Team -> Share Project` and enter all my svn data that eclipse needs for connecting to the repository.

During commit process I get following error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
svn: PROPFIND of '/myproject/.buildpath':
     500 Internal Server Error (http://svn.mydomain.net)
```

Any ideas whats wrong here? No data is transfered to my repository.

The vhost.conf for my subdomain looks like that

```
    ServerName svn.mydomain.de
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Location />
        DAV svn

        SVNParentPath /var/svn

        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setup of the SVN Server cause it looks like there is no repository been created or wrongly configured.

Comment: I have setup subversion according to this how to http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/ what else needs to be configured?

Comment: But the howto says to use the following url: http://www.mydomain.com/svn and not http://svn.mydomain.net/myproject ?

Comment: thats not the problem, I have setup a subdomain to serve the repo and that works fine

Comment: Sorry but the error messages above give me the impression that it is not working fine.....How does you configuration for apache look like? If you have setup'd a sub-domain does the sub-domain contain the Location Tag ? How does the SVNPath look like?

Comment: Ah...have you create a repository under the folder /var/svn like svnadmin create /var/svn/repository or maybe you have to change the SVNParentPath entry into SVNPath ? But check if you have created a repository under /var/svn already...if so change SVNParentPath to SVNPath..

Comment: /var/svn is the root for all svn projects
so e.g. /var/svn/myproject would be a project and I would browse it with svn.mydomain.de/myproject
this works in the browser
I also connected this repo with my project management system (redmine) and it works fine, now I want to transfere my project from eclipse to svn and this fails^^

Comment: Than you have to do an import into the repository first. After that you have to do a checkout of your project and then you can continue working...

Comment: How do I do the import. do you have a link to a how to?

Comment: actually I do it like this but it fails http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/index.html#section5_0